# What svn client does git-svn use?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, client, version

I am stuck working with an old svn repository that has a bunch of 1.4.4 clients in use. I would like to start working with git again (mainly so I can get some easy local branching).

Side note:
I just went through the horrific process of doing a branch (copy) in svn and merging it back into trunk only to discover that svn throws away commit history when you do a merge (why?!?)!

Anyway, I have been doing clone and rebase operations with git-svn but have been worried about pushing (git svn dcommit) since I don't want to move the svn repo version forward invalidating all the 1.4.4 clients in use out there.

Is it possible to define the svn client used by git? Does it just use the one on the path or is it using an embedded client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running git on Microsoft Windows the installer uses [`msysGit`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/What-is-msysGit,-what-is-Git-for-Windows).

Looking at this [`msysGit` commit messages](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/tree/ab173bb3bc3852b04e2958abac61bc6f65c7a64a/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys/SVN) it seems that **Subversion 1.4.6** was installed.

Comment: Among the [```msysGit``` FAQ](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) you can read why [Subversion is too old](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Subversion-is-too-old), and [how to upgrade Subversion](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/I-want-to-upgrade-Subversion.-How-do-I-do-that).

Comment: I am wondering if a 1.4.6 client will bump up the repository version number, i.e. will 1.4.4 clients still work on a repo that is touched by a 1.4.6 client?

Comment: @RyanR. I'm quite confident that backward compatibility is maintained especially by a patch version (major.minor.patch) variation. But, just for clarity, are you speaking about upgrading the subversion server?

Comment: nope, keeping the subversion server as is. I just want to know if I start pushing (dcommit) with git-svn to the existing server if the 1.4.4 clients are going to stop working with it. I have experienced this problem in the past with different subversion client versions but am unsure in this case with the minor release (as you mentioned).

Comment: @RyanR. We have a 1.6 Subversion server repository we daily access to through: IDE by SVNKit, IDE by JavaHL 1.7.10, Windows Graphical File System by Tortoise SVN 1.6.16, WIN32 command line by svn 1.6.17-SlikSvn, WIN32 command line by svn 1.7.5-SlikSvn. One or two developer had little problems after upgrading but they resolved doing a cleanup or re-checking out the entire project in a new working directory; all other developers had none problems.